# Delete/retrieve an element from an array

Tags: python

When an element from an array is deleted using del, is it possible to retrieve the deleted element..

```
del_ele = []
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
del_ele.append(del arr[6])
```

Comment: A ``[ ]`` is not an array in Python, it is a list. What an array is in Python is described here: (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `pop` method.

```
del_ele.append(arr.pop(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. 
Quoting from (http://www.python.org/doc//current/reference/simple_stmts.html#del): 
Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace,...